# Clear data when removeUI used

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am using observeEvent to insert a UI (in the example below, it adds an additional numeric input box) with `insertUI` and likewise observeEvent to remove those UIs via `removeUI`. The issue is that the data that is created through those UIs does not clear or reset. In the example below, you can enter numbers in separate numeric input boxes and press `Go!` to sum them together. Upon removing elements, it should clear our that data and re-sum, but it keeps the last number added.

For example, if 1 is in the first box and two more input boxes are added, both with 1s, pressing `Go!` correctly sums them to 3. However, removing the two text boxes and pressing `Go!` keeps 3 when it should just show 1.

I am sure I have missed something simple. My reprex is below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("example"),

    # button input
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput(
                "number",
                "A Number 1-10",
                1,
                min = 1,
                max = 10,
                step = NA,
                width = NULL),
            #add/remove buttons
            fluidRow(column(
                6,
                actionButton('insertBtn', 'Add Number'), 
                actionButton('removeBtn', 'Remove Number'), 
                tags$div(id = 'placeholder') 
            )),
            # go button
            fluidRow(column(
                6, actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Go!"),
            ))
        ),

        # output
        mainPanel(
            htmlOutput("total")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # add text boxes when clicked
    
    inserted <- c()
    
    observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {

    btn <- input$insertBtn
    id <- paste0('number', btn)
    insertUI(
        selector = '#placeholder',
        ## wrap element in a div with id for ease of removal
        ui = tags$div(
            fluidRow(
                numericInput(
                   id,
                    "A Number 1-10",
                    1,
                    min = 1,
                    max = 10,
                    step = NA,
                    width = NULL)
            ),
            id = id)
    )
    inserted <<- c(id, inserted)
})

    # remove text boxes
observeEvent(input$removeBtn, {
    removeUI(
        ## pass in appropriate div id
        selector = paste0('#', inserted[length(inserted)])
    )
    inserted <<- inserted[-length(inserted)]
})

# add numbers in boxes

final_number_text <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    
    
    btn <- input$insertBtn
    if(btn > 0){
        
        total <- input$number
        
        for(i in 1:btn){
            
            total<- total+ (input[[paste0("number", i)]])
        }
        
        
    } else {
        
        total <- input$number
        
    }
    
    HTML(paste(total))
})

output$total <- renderText({
    final_number_text()
})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that when you remove a number, you are not decreasing the value of `input$insertBtn`.  Therefore, you want to count only the elements that are in `inserted`.  Therefore, replace

```
for(i in 1:btn){...}
```

with

```
lapply(inserted, function(par) {total <<- total + input[[par]]})
```

Full code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("example"),

  # button input
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(
        "number",
        "A Number 1-10",
        1,
        min = 1,
        max = 10,
        step = NA,
        width = NULL),
      #add/remove buttons
      fluidRow(column(
        6,
        actionButton('insertBtn', 'Add Number'),
        actionButton('removeBtn', 'Remove Number'),
        tags$div(id = 'placeholder')
      )),
      # go button
      fluidRow(column(
        6, actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Go!"),
      ))
    ),

    # output
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("total")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # add text boxes when clicked

  inserted <- c()

  observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {

    btn <- input$insertBtn
    id <- paste0('number', btn)
    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholder',
      ## wrap element in a div with id for ease of removal
      ui = tags$div(
        fluidRow(
          numericInput(
            id,
            "A Number 1-10",
            1,
            min = 1,
            max = 10,
            step = NA,
            width = NULL)
        ),
        id = id)
    )
    # inserted <<- c(id, inserted) ##  removes first one first
    inserted <<- c(inserted, id)   ##  removes last one first
  })

  # remove text boxes
  observeEvent(input$removeBtn, {
    removeUI(
      ## pass in appropriate div id
      selector = paste0('#', inserted[length(inserted)])
    )
    
    inserted <<- inserted[-length(inserted)]
  })

  # add numbers in boxes
  final_number_text <- eventReactive(input$go, {

    total <- input$number
    if(length(inserted) > 0){
      lapply(inserted, function(par) {total <<- total + input[[par]]})
    }

    HTML(paste(total))
  })

  output$total <- renderText({
    final_number_text()
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

We may need `seq_along` which would be bug free when the length is 0

```
for(i in seq_along(inserted)) {...}
```

Comment: Please note that this does not work if someone deletes a input box, and then decides to add more.  For example, when `ID`s are `number1, number3, number4`, the value for `i` in `seq_along()` will be 1,2,3 resulting in incorrect total.

Comment: @YBS Your `1:btn` also have an issue as I mentioned in the length

Comment: sorry, I do not use `btn` in the `eventReactive` object, as `inserted` can be `0` while `input$insertBtn` will be `>0` once the actionButton is clicked at least once.  Please see the full code below.

Comment: I agree that seq_along is definitely better than 1:length.

Comment: @YBS I know that you are a master in shiny so you know a lot more than me.  My comment was more of general